# Prove that the complement of a subspace is unique up to isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

V is a vector space. S is a subspace of V. Complement of S is S1, s.t. V is the direct sum of S and S1. Now is S1 unique up to isomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not assuming $V$ finite dimensional, I give an answer that does not involve dimensions.

Let $V=S_S\oplus S_1$. Then there is a natural isomorphism $V/S\to S_1$. In fact, take the first projection $V\to S_1$ given by $(v_0,v_1)\mapsto v_1$, which is surjective and whose kernel is exacty $S$.

So any two complements of $S$ are naturally isomorphic. Of course the complement is not unique, for example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ any non-horizontal line is a complement of the $x$-axis.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot an condition.I want to prove that S1 is unique up to isomorphism. So how to prove?

Comment: That's exactly what I proved :) any complement is isomorphic to $V/S$, so any two of them must be isomorphic!

Answer (score 0):

Assume $S_1,S_2\subseteq V$ with $S\oplus S_1=S\oplus S_2=V$. Then 
we have the embedding $\iota_1\colon S_1\to V$ and the projection $\pi_2\colon V=S\oplus S_2\to S_2$,  $(x,y)\mapsto y$. This gives us a linear map $\pi_2\circ \iota_1\colon S_1\to S_2$, which is injective because $x\in\ker(\pi_2\circ \iota_1)$ implies $x=\iota_1(x)\in\ker(\pi_2)=S$ and so $x=0$. This implies $\sim S_1\le \dim S_2$. By a symmetric argument we find $\dim  S_2\le \dim S_1$, hence $\dim S_1=\dim S_2$ and indeed $S_1\cong S_2$.

Comment: I want to prove that S1 is unique. In your case, it means S1= S2. That the dimention of S1,S2 are the same doesn't mean that S1=S2

Comment: You can show $S_1=S_2$ only if $S=V$. Also, I thought you wanted to show uniqueness *up to isomorphism*?